# Google My Business API error on updating the primary category

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

When updating the primary category using Google My Business API, it shows this error:

```
+"error": {#278 ▼
    +"code": 400
    +"message": "Request contains an invalid argument."
    +"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    +"details": array:1 [▼
      0 => {#269 ▼
        +"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"
        +"fieldViolations": array:1 [▼
          0 => {#275 ▼
            +"field": "update_mask"
            +"description": "primary or additional categories cannot be updated independently."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Here's my PHP Code :

```
<?php

$locationData = array();
$locationData['title'] = $data['title'];
$locationData['categories']['primaryCategory']['name'] = 'gcid:website_designer';

$updateMask = array(
    'title', 
    'categories.primaryCategory.name'
);

$queryParams = array(
    'updateMask' => implode(',', $updateMask)
);

// Prepare new cURL resource
$curl = curl_init('https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/locations/'.$locationId.'/?'.http_build_query($queryParams));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $locationData);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
));

// Submit the DELETE request
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Close cURL session handle
curl_close($curl);

$location = json_decode($response);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($location);
echo "</pre>";
```

What does this error means?

```
primary or additional categories cannot be updated independently.
```

it successfully update the business name when I removed this mask

```
categories.primaryCategory.name
```

So, I'm confused what mask should I add to update the primary category or is there a separate API for that?

I based on this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations/patch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update mask you need to specify just `categories` and supply both.
Same goes for `phoneNumbers`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although the details of the API changes are not clearly communicated, the change log mentions PhoneNumbers and Categories (https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/businessinformation/change-log).